# Unable to communicate from one Docker container to an exposed container on the same machine

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, firewall, iptables

Currently I'm trying to make one container communicate with another one that is exposed and running on the same machine.

Lets say the external IP address is `123.123.123.123` and I exposed a basic NGINX Docker container on port `8080` via the `ports` property inside my `docker-compose.yaml` and I execute `curl http://123.123.123.123:8080`. From an external machine it successfully gets a response back, same goes for executing the command from the host machine. However when I execute this curl from another container on the same machine it exits with a timeout.

I'm unsure of the cause, I have tried temporarily exposing all ports via https://serverfault.com/a/129087 and this did actually allow communication from one container to the exposed container (Of course I restored the previous configuration afterwards).

It is important for me to be able to use the external routing, especially since in production `jwilder/nginx-proxy` is used with HTTPS certificates.

The machine is running Ubuntu 20.04, I haven't altered any firewall settings provided by iptables.

`ufw status` output:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     LIMIT       Anywhere                  
2375/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
2376/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)             
2375/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
2376/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Probably the most relevant part of `iptables -L`:

```
Chain DOCKER (6 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:9000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.2           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.6           tcp dpt:mysql
```

Curious how this issue could be fixed. Of course adding both containers to the same internal network fixes this, but since port `8080` is already exposed to the world I would like this to include internal traffic as well. I'm using Docker Compose, both of these containers are not apart of the same `docker-compose.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was staring in my face all this time. Basically with [this image provided by DigitalOcean](https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/docker) both iptables and UFW are enabled at the same time. However Docker is not able to expose ports whenever you add one to your Docker configuration.

Apparently that mostly isn't a problem for external traffic since in this scenario UFW apparently does not handle external traffic, that is all up to iptables. Adding `ufw allow http` and `ufw allow https` fixes it!